# Add a Visible Timestamp to Cypress Screenshots

Tags: datetime, cypress

Since Cypress is only able to take screenshots within the browser window, it doesn't include a timestamp. It appears this functionality available.

Is there some way to include a date/time stamp on the screen capture?

Comment: Cypress itself doesn't provide a built-in feature to include timestamps in screenshots, you can achieve this by leveraging JavaScript and Cypress together. i had very similar situation as yours. pasted my code in the answer section.

Comment: Please put your biographical details in the correct place - your profile page.

Comment: If you are looking to have a some form of measurement for performance/speed, then the timestamps you seek with Cypress will include some overhead and will not be accurate.

Answer (score 3):

Cypress provides screenshot hooks, you can find the documentation here [Change the DOM using onBeforeScreenshot and onAfterScreenshot](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/screenshot-api#Change-the-DOM-using-onBeforeScreenshot-and-onAfterScreenshot).

You can provide a timestamp like this

```js
let timestamp;
Cypress.Screenshot.defaults({
  onBeforeScreenshot($el) {
    timestamp = document.createElement('span')
    timestamp.innerText = new Date().toLocaleString("de-DE")
    $el[0].appendChild(timestamp)
  },
  onAfterScreenshot($el, props) {
    timestamp.remove()
  },
})
```