# Time stamp in cypress screenshots

Tags: automated-tests, cypress, screenshot

I want to add time stamp in top left corner of the screenshot . I am looking for JavaScript code mixed with cypress methods to achieve this functionality

I am able to add timestamp in the bottom left corner but somehow I am not able to any other place

Comment: Can you say why you want it in that position?

Comment: thats the requirement I need to acheive. I am a Qa Engineer, modifying dom on real time without use of inbuilt Cypress commands has become difficult for me. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question is not really up to the guidelines for this site, which are given here [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). As it stands, your question feels more like a request for tutorial. Can you improve the question to be more in line with the guidelines?

Answer (score 2):

You have seen the answer here [Add a Visible Timestamp to Cypress Screenshots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76475670/add-a-visible-timestamp-to-cypress-screenshots).

The exact positioning depends quite a bit on the page you are working with.

But to go to top-left instead of bottom-left, the obvious thing to try is `insertBefore()` instead of `appendChild()`.

```js
let timestamp;
Cypress.Screenshot.defaults({
  onBeforeScreenshot($el) {
    timestamp = document.createElement('span')
    timestamp.innerText = new Date().toLocaleString("de-DE")
    const $body = $el.find('body')
    $el[0].insertBefore(timestamp, $body[0])
  },
  onAfterScreenshot($el, props) {
    timestamp.remove()
  },
})
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick answer, can you please also provide code if I want to have the datetime in a box. with good visual design. Thanks !!